# How to run a dynamic REST URL inside a loop in C# - Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, url, rest

How can i run a URL in c#
I dont want to open the link on the browser...just run the url on background by the program.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to make the call to a given URL and then parse the data accordingly. This can be spun off in a `BackgroundWorker` if so desired, as to not block the UI thread.

```
HttpWebRequest request = null;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/orders?OrderNum=" + "i");
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        //ignore 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use the `WebClient' class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't need any response. I just want to insert some data. with a REST command(URL). So in a loop i want to run the dynamic URLs, that insert some data.

Comment: i tried httpwebrequest and webclient before i post here. Only webclient made the entry but only managed to make 2 loops. It should do 32.

Comment: @heav3n You will need to modify your HttpWebRequest with each call, make sure you are doing that within your loop, modified answer to provide a rudimentary example.

Comment: yes i dynamically change the URL but it doesnt run for some reason